# Laravel: Why var_dump/dump/dd affect auth()->login() function

Tags: php, laravel

## Env

- laravel 5.5

## Issue

I wrote two small test routes (web route):

```
Route::get('/test/login', function (){

    auth()->login(\App\User::find(1));
//    dump('hello');

    return response()->json(['msg'=>'login succeed!']);

});

Route::get('/test/me', function (){

    return response()->json(auth()->user());

});
```

When I do `GET /test/login` and then do `GET /test/me`, the user data will be return as expected.

However, if I **uncomment** dump part `dump('hello');`, then follow the same sequence as above, I get **empty data** for `GET /test/me`.

BTW, I use 'file' as session driver.

## Questions

I wonder WHY and HOW var_dump/dump/dd make auth()->login() not work as normal?

Comment: first of all, [`dd` stops the execution](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-dd) and prints the data as the response. [`dump()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/56a58e0fa3d845bb992d7c64ac9bb6d0c24b745a/src/Illuminate/Support/Debug/Dumper.php#L23) on the other hand, simply calls `var_dump`. while `var_dump` will print the data on where it is called. since on your code when you call those function in non-user-response printing. it will end up with empty response instead. cmiiw.

Comment: I found if I use var_dump/dump/dd anywhere of the login request, there is no cookies (laravel_session, XSRF-TOKEN, etc) with response. If I removed var_dump/dump/dd, it has. maybe that is the reason, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that explained this. see
[laracasts-answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cookie-setting-doesnt-work-if-i-use-dump-function)

> Once you send some content to be displayed in the browser, you cannot send a header anymore. var_dump(dump, or dd) will send response header (without cookie), so after that response with cookie doesn't work, because you cannot send response anymore.

Login problem in my case in the end is about session/cookie, if no `laravel_session` cookie set in the response header, then session and login based on session cannot work normally.